# How to find if and where is installed firebird in delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, search, path, registry

Problem: I need to modify aliases.conf in firebird but.. as we know the user can install firebird anywhere he want. So I need to programmatically find out where the firebird was installed. I try to do that by registry but it's not good idea because withe almost every one new version of windows (2000, XP, VISTA, 7, 8 and 32 bit or 64 bit and may be 128 bit) the registry keys get change. I try also find out procedure for searching registry like simple text file but no result. I have try to find the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs\aliases.conf" but it's not simple way. It's possible that the problem is not in registry function just in Lazarus but I do not know that. So, may be some one has any idea how to check if and where is installed firebird. Shortly say: I'm going to install my application with database file and have to have silently modify the aliases.conf.

Comment: Give up on it, ask the user. Firebird might not have been locally installed. Worse, there might be a local, inactive installation, and a remote running server. That would be the case if I installed your program...

Comment: "aliases.conf" is not a DLL, so there's no reason to expect it to be in the `SharedDLL` registry entry. You shouldn't be "silently modifying" anything that concerns the user's database configuration, as you could break another (possibly critical) application that isn't yours.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the installation location of Firebird by checking the registry key `HKLM\Software\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances` and reading the `DefaultInstance` value.

The following code should do the trick :-

```
var
  lReg : TRegistry;
  lStr : String;
begin
  lReg := TRegistry.Create;
  Try
    lReg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    If lReg.OpenKey('Software\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances', False) Then
      lStr := lReg.ReadString('DefaultInstance');
    lReg.CloseKey;
    ShowMessage(lStr);
  Finally
    FreeAndNil(lReg);
  End;
```

Comment: Andy_D I have use this function but is not work. function TfrMain.GetSubKeys(ARegStr: string; var SubKeys: TStringList): boolean;
var Reg: TRegistry;
begin
     SubKeys := nil;
     Reg := TRegistry.create;
     try
       if Reg.OpenKey(ARegStr, false) then
        begin
          SubKeys := TStringList.Create;
          Reg.GetKeyNames(SubKeys);
          Reg.CloseKey;
        end;
     finally
      Reg.free;
     end;
     Result := SubKeys <> nil;
end;

Comment: What result do you get? Is Firebird installed on your PC Have you checked the registry values using RegEdit?

Comment: Your registry function doesn't work. I've updated my answer with a function that works perfectly on 3 machines I have at my disposal with Firebird installed on them.

Comment: In regedt I do not have that key. I found just HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs\aliases.conf but as you know an other computer with other stupid windows this key will not work. If I could search the key by using just part name of key for example just "aliases.conf" then would be great.

Comment: Yes, yes I have installed Firebird. The result was Nil.

Comment: If that key doesn't exist then Firebird isn't installed on the PC. The code I posted will give you the installation folder of Firebird and from there you can get to Aliases.Conf.

Comment: Hey! YOUR FUNCTION WORKS PERFECTLY !!!! Do you think it will work on Windows XP? Could you give me your e-mail? I have no friend which I could speak about Delphi. I have a lot of experiences in Delphi but in  different level.

Comment: This seems to be the correct way. Look at the `GetFirebirdDir` function from [`this setup script`](http://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/code/HEAD/tree/firebird/trunk/builds/install/arch-specific/win32/FirebirdInstallEnvironmentChecks.inc). Kazmirus, if this post helped you to resolve your question, you may consider accepting it [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). And yes, this will work even on Windows XP.

Comment: Thanx to everybody! Thats it what I need. Every answer was a very, very good helpful. Thanks a lot.